# POST request being redirected to GET on form submit

Tags: express, parse-platform

I use parse.com with their expressjs framework. 
I have this html form which calls my /login url with post but for some reason it gets redirected(with status code 301) to a get request to that url.

This is my html form

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="/login">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input name="username"></input>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password"></input>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Log In">
  </form>
</body>
```

To make the question more clear i use express js with parse.com and here are the two routing defined

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.send('get is called');
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.send('post is called');
});
```

Now no matter what i provide in my form method i always get "get is called" in the browser on submitting the button.

I also tried to debug what is happening in by the developer console and this is what i get

[image]

Comment: I just executed your example and the browser renders "post is called." Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Did you restart node after you edited your files?

Comment: this is all the code i have. If you see the screenshot i pasted, the post is indeed being called. It just gets redirected to GET from the server. parse.com support express js to do all these operations.

Comment: @Nikita, i am using parse.com for server side. I can only redeploy not restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using ejs template try adding all the attributes in your form as without double quotes, something like this and try

```
<html>
<head></head> 
<body>
  <form method=post action=/login>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input name="username"></input>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password"></input>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Log In">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked in the console and the form attributes when double quotes were added was something of this sort

```
<form action=""/login"" method=""POST"">
```

so by default the form was getting submitted as a GET request instead of a POST. I am still not sure why this is happening, just started learning express, will add more details when I get them.